# How can I check that the Process class from Python Multiprocessing has worked?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

I've written the following code which runs a function that simulates a stochastic simulation of a series of chemical reactions. I've written the following code:

```
v = range(1, 51)
def parallelfunc(*v):     
    gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    start = datetime.utcnow()
    p = Process(target=parallelfunc, args=(v))
    p.start()    
    p.join()
    end = datetime.utcnow()
    sim_time = end - start
    print(f"Simualtion utc time:\n{sim_time}")
```

I'm using the Process method from the multiprocessing library and am trying to run `gillespie_tau_leaping` 50 times.

Only I'm not sure if its working. `gillespie_tau_leaping` prints out a number of values to the terminal, but these values are only printed out once, I'd expect them to be printed out 50 times.

I tried using the `getpid` etc command and this returns the following to the terminal:

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 6188
process id: 27920
```

How can I tell if my code as worked and how can I get it to print the values from `gillepsie_tau_leaping` 50 times to the terminal?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running just one process, the call to `Process`, spawns a new thread but you are doing it only once (not in a loop).

I would suggest you to use [multiprocessing pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)
Your code can be something like this:

```
from multiprocess import Pool
def parallelfunc(*args):
    do_something()

def main():
   # create a list of list of args for the function invocation
   func_args = [['arg1call1', 'arg2call1', 'arg3call1'], ['arg1call2', 'arg2call2', 'arg3call2']]
   with Pool() as p:
      results = p.map(parallelfunc, func_args)
   # do something with results which is a list of results
```

`multiprocessing` pool by default create the same number of processes as your CPU cores and manage the process Pool till the end of the processing taking care of all the Inter Process Communication.
This is really handy because synchronizing processes can be hard.

Hope this helps